# How to spy a function with Sinon.js that is in the same js file as the function under test

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, sinon, spy

I have a problem with Sinon.js while trying to spy a function that is in the same javascript file as the function that I want to test. Furthermore I assert that the spied function is called once. Unfortunately the test fails. Interesting thing is, that if the spied function is in another javascript file than the function under test it works !

Here is my code:

mock_test.js:

```js
   
var sinon = require('sinon')

var one = require('./one.js')
var two = require('./two.js')

describe('Spy ', function () {

  it('Spy another method', sinon.test(function (done) {
    var another_method_spy = sinon.spy(one, 'another_method')

    one.some_method()
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(another_method_spy)
    done()
  }))

  it('Spy second method', sinon.test(function (done) {
    var second_method = sinon.spy(two, 'second')

    one.call_second()
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(second_method)
    done()
  }))

})
```

one.js:

```js
var two = require('./two.js')

var some_method = function(){
  console.log('one: some method')
  another_method()
}

var another_method = function(){
  console.log('one: another method')
}

var call_second = function(){
  console.log('one: call second')
  two.second()
}

module.exports.some_method = some_method
module.exports.another_method = another_method
module.exports.call_second = call_second
```

two.js:

```js
var second = function(){
  console.log('two: second')
}

module.exports.second = second
```

I couldn't find anything helpful in the internet and also I tried different things. Please help, what am I missing here ?

Cheers 
Noah

Comment: So in this case, the `Spy another method` test is not working, while the `Spy second method` test is working?

Comment: @MitchLillie Exactly

Comment: What have you ruled out? Specifically, I'm thinking: 1. Anything at all that is async happening in `some_method` or `another_method` in your actual code, 2. Another assertion library, 3. Does using `called` (instead of `calledOnce`) work?

Comment: @MitchLillie for 1 it's not relevant if there is async stuff in the methods, it doesn't work for sync and async stuff, for 2 yes I tried, didn't work :/, for 3 didn't work either ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately the test fails

That is because `one.some_method()` in **mock_test.js** invokes `another_method` inside the closure `one.some_method()` is holding over the content of **one.js** and not `one.another_method` in **mock_test.js**.

### Illustration by example

Lets re-write one.js to:

```
var a = 'I am exported';
var b = 'I am not exported';

function foo () {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(this.b)
}

module.exports.a=a;
module.exports.foo=foo;
```

and mock_test.js to:

```
var one = require('./one');

console.log(one); // { a: 'I am exported', foo: [Function: foo] }

one.a = 'Charles';
one.b = 'Diana';

console.log(one); // { a: 'Charles', foo: [Function: foo], b: 'Diana' }
```

Now if we invoke `one.foo()` it will result in:

```
I am exported
Diana
```

The `I am exported` is logged to the console because `console.log(a)` inside `foo` points to `var a` inside the closure `foo` is holding over the contents of **one.js**.

The `Diana` is logged to the console because `console.log(this.b)` inside `foo` points to `one.b` in **mock_test.js**.

### So what do you need to do to make it work?

You need to change:

```
var some_method = function(){
  console.log('one: some method')
  another_method()
}
```

to:

```
var some_method = function(){
  console.log('one: some method')
  this.another_method()
}
```