# Stubs and proxquire

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon, proxyquire

I'm having an issue with stubbing a particular function with sinon after having used proxyquire.

Example:

```
// a.js
const api = require('api');

module.exports = (function () {
    return {
        run,
        doStuff
    };

    function run() {
        return api()
            .then((data) => {
                return doStuff(data);
            })
    }

    function doStuff(data) {
        return `Got data: ${data}`;
    }
})()

// a.spec.js - in the test
a = proxyquire('./a', {
    'api': () => Promise.resolve('data')
})
sinon.stub(a, 'doStuff');
// RUN TEST - call a.run()
```

I know it isn't working because it calls the original doStuff instead of a mocked/stubbed doStuff.

Comment: It kind of depends what you're trying to test. Are you trying to test that `doStuff` is called? Are you trying to test internal logic inside `doStuff`? Are you trying to make sure a certain value is returned from `run`?

Comment: @JamesENL I'm testing run. I just want to check what doStuff is called with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spy a function with Sinon.js that is in the same js file as the function under test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660832/how-to-spy-a-function-with-sinon-js-that-is-in-the-same-js-file-as-the-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it isn't working because it calls the original doStuff instead
>   of a mocked/stubbed doStuff.

That is because `function run()` in **a.js** invokes `function doStuff(data)` inside the closure `function run()` is holding over the content of **a.js** and not `function doStuff(data)` in **a_spec.js**.

### Illustration by example

Lets re-write a.js to:

```
var a = 'I am exported';
var b = 'I am not exported';

function foo () {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(this.b)
}

module.exports.a=a;
module.exports.foo=foo;
```

and a.spec.js to:

```
var one = require('./one');

console.log(one); // { a: 'I am exported', foo: [Function: foo] }

one.a = 'Charles';
one.b = 'Diana';

console.log(one); // { a: 'Charles', foo: [Function: foo], b: 'Diana' }
```

Now if we invoke `one.foo()` it will result in:

```
I am exported
Diana
```

The `I am exported` is logged to the console because `console.log(a)` inside `foo` points to `var a` inside the closure `foo` is holding over the contents of **a.js**.

The `Diana` is logged to the console because `console.log(this.b)` inside `foo` points to `one.b` in **a.spec.js**.

### So what do you need to do to make it work?

You need to change:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    return {
        run,
        doStuff
    };

    function run() {
        return api()
            .then((data) => {
                return doStuff(data);
            })
    }

    function doStuff(data) {
        return `Got data: ${data}`;
    }
})()
```

to:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    return {
        run,
        doStuff
    };

    function run() {
        return api()
            .then((data) => {
                return this.doStuff(data); // ´this.doStuff´ points to ´doStuff´ in the exported object
            }.bind(this)) // to ensure that ´this´ does not point to the global object
    }

    function doStuff(data) {
        return `Got data: ${data}`;
    }
})()
```

Comment: What is his.another_method()

Comment: @kjonsson: Something that should not have been there. Has been deleted.